# Rolling back temporarily, and pushing to origin ahead of local branch

Tags: git

#### The Situation

We made a special promotional version of our website, and management asked as it to push it live, which we did.  Assume that, starting from the normal site (call it commit 0 for simplicity), it took us 5 commits to create the promo version, and all of those commits were made on master (so the working promo site is commit 5).

Now we get an emergency call: The promo dates we were originally given are wrong, the promo's not supposed to start until next week.  Please rollback to the original site immediately.

#### Assume the following

1. We have a post-receive hook setup on origin that will push live any commits it receives.
2. We need the site to rollback to commit 0 right now.
3. In about a week we'll need our changes from commit 5 again.
4. We expect a few bug fixes to be added between now and next week.

#### Question

What series of git commands is appropriate to solve this problem?

Here is one idea, which I think will work but seems suboptimal:

1. `git branch promo` to save our our promo work for later
2. `git reset --hard 0` to rollback to the normal site
3. `git push -f origin master` to push the normal site live again.  We need to the "force" flag otherwise git will complain that origin is ahead of our local branch.
4. Do some bug commits on master, on top of commit 0, that create commits 6 and 7 during the week.
5. `git merge promo` and `git push origin master` when next week arrives, and it's time to actually push the promo version of the site live again.

So, is there a better way to do this?  Should I be using revert instead of reset?  Is there a way to avoid the awkward `-f` force flag?  Other comments?

Comment: You could use `git revert` to revert the top 5 commits. Then when you're ready for the promo, just revert the reverts.

Comment: @xbonez, would the bug fixes that happen during the week cause any problems with that plan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the point 5, I would rather rebase `promo` on top of `master`.

```
 git checkout promo
 git rebase master
 git checkout master
 git merge promo     # fast-forward master HEAD to promo HEAD
 git push
```

That way you keep a linear history while testing the integration of promo with the bugfixes you did (commit 6 and 7).

Comment: Good point.  Does the rest of it look okay to you?  Nothing wrong with the reset and force push?

Comment: @Jonah The force pushed is only an issue if other devs are cloning or updating from that repo on the server. If not, a forced push is fine.

Comment: What would you do if other devs were working on/cloning from that repo?

Comment: @Jonah Simply ask them to reset their master branches to origin/master (stashing their un-committed work in progress if they have one). It looks cumbersome, but it also enforces a good communication amongst the team, making sure everybody is aware of the particular nature of the situation (reset to commit 0)

Comment: That makes sense, and I'm sure will cover me for 95% of real world cases.  For the sake of learning, though, what would be the solution in the case of, say, a large team all using the same repo -- where we couldn't make any assumptions about other people following our directions, and needed an airtight solution?

Comment: @Jonah then `git revert` is fine, but you would see duplicate history (the 5 commits published twice)

Answer (score 2):

As a rule, I don't like rewriting history; changes always move forward. I would do this.

```
# Keep a copy of the promo state
git branch promo

# Undo the changes
git revert 0
git push
```

Do your work on the "promo" branch. You can rebase, merge from "master", do whatever you like.

Then, when it really is time:

```
git merge promo
git push
```

Comment: does the revert essentially make a new commit 6 which is identical in content to commit 0?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly it. The advantage is that you can say why this happened in the commit log, and you can relate server logs back to the correct commit, by date, etc.